# Fourier Transform of $t\cdot f(t)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to show the fourier transform of $$t\cdot f(t)$$ is $$i \cdot \frac {d\widetilde{f}(\omega)}{d\omega} $$

I have tried to follow [this](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/tg.php) example but I get lost when $$\frac{dG(f)}{df} = \frac{dF\{ g(t)\} }{df}$$

I know that $ g(t)\cdot t$ is the function being transformed and this first step is working to prove that the transform of $g(t)$ is $G(t)$ and it exists but what allows me to define $G(f) = F\{ g(t)\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good function $f$,
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-it\omega}dt,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{d\omega}\widehat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{d}{d\omega}(f(t)e^{-it\omega})dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)(-it)e^{-it\omega}dt=-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf(t)e^{-it\omega}dt,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
i\dfrac{d}{d\omega}\widehat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf(t)e^{-it\omega}dt=\hat{(tf(t))}(\omega).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, I follow everything up to the last line where t f(t) is to the power omega. Why is this?

Comment: That is simply the Fourier transform of the function $tf(t)$ at $\omega$, this is the goal of your question.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thank you